# Connecting and refreshing data in various components

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, viewmodel

I have MainView in which I have created TabView with 3 different views:
ViewA, ViewB, ViewC.
I also have three definitions of ViewModels:

```
@StateObject private var viewModelA: ViewModelA = ViewModelA()
@StateObject private var viewModelB: ViewModelB = ViewModelB()
@StateObject private var viewModelC: ViewModelC = ViewModelC()
```

Each view model is passed to corresponding view with `.environmentObject` modifier, for example `ViewA().environmentObject(viewModelA)` so it can be used in ViewA's subviews.

My main concern is that `ViewC` and `ViewModelC` have functionality that changes data from **database** in app. The same database data is used in `ViewA` and therefore in `ViewModelA`. I want the data in `A` be refreshed when some action from `C` finishes. All **ViewModels** have access to database data through **Interactors** or **Synchronizers**

I know I can achieve this by passing `viewModelA` to `viewC` as an `environmentObject` and then execute some `viewModelA's` function when some other action from `C` finishes, however I don't know if it is a correct practise.
I also thought of creating some singleton that would be injectable in every View or ViewModel and it would have some property `needsToBeRefresh: Bool` that would tell me to update different Views or ViewModels

What would be the best solution in my case?

Comment: I would provide some common object to all three view models. It doesn't need to be a singleton though, just a single instance that is provided to all 3

Comment: A _ViewModel_  instance in a MVVM pattern  has a 1:1 relation ship with a single view instance and sharing this instance with other views is definitely a bad thing to do. I also question the architecture, since you have an "Interactor".  In the worst case, the Interactor is an Object sharing mutable state and  an instance will be shared by several ViewModels. An architecture that calls for troubles! Replace your Interactor with a set of functions, one of it returning a _Publisher_, where the ViewModel can react on changes.

Comment: `needsToBeRefresh` is a terrible practice, there is something much deeper going on if you need to manually tell SwiftUI to reload. Also, remember that in MVVM, the VM is attached to 1 View, multiple views don't need to access or need to know about multiple VM.

Answer (score -1):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already, you shouldn't be trying to reimplement it in a class or you'll run into major issues. `@StateObject` is actually designed for when you need a reference type in `@State`, e.g. for doing something asynchronous like loading/saving data, or using a Combine pipeline. Since now we have async/await using the `.task` modifier we don't actually even need `@StateObject` any more.